# How to execute multiple task sequentially(queue) in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing multiple file transfer using AsyncTask.
Different file path stored in a arraylist, my problem is how to send all the files in a queue(sequentially).

[image]

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>   super.onResume();
>   /*
>    * Some logic
>    */
>   new XYZAsyncTask (mString).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
> }
> ```
>
> private class XYZAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
>
> ```
>     ArrayList<String> mArray;
>
>     @Override
>     protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList... params) {
>         /*
>          * 
>          * Some logic
>          */
>         checkSizeAndSendFile();
>         return null;
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please post current code you are using.

Answer (score 4):

> I am doing multiple file transfer using AsyncTask

That's unlikely to be a good idea. Use an `IntentService`, so that your process is likely to be around long enough for the file transfers to complete. As a side benefit, `IntentService` has a built-in queue — just use separate `startService()` calls for each transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didnt get your question, but why not just pass the filenames and iterate over them, like this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... files) {
    for (String file : files) {
    // handle each individual files here
    }
}
```